# In Google Analytics - how do I link directly to today's statistics?

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics, I am trying to create a link that navigates directly to **today's statistics**.

When choosing today's date from the menu, it populates the URL with the date range selected, as follows:

`.../_u.date00=20190130&_u.date01=20190130/`

Is it possible to create a dynamic populates today's date? Such as:

`.../_u.date00=today()&_u.date01=today()/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an unsupported way, you could set your dates to something in the future:

```
.../_u.date00=21190130&_u.date01=21190130/
```

Comment: Great answer! Works like a charm. Thank you!